# How to get the actual time information of the video recorded with varying frame rate?

Tags: video, video-streaming, computer-vision, video-processing, video-encoding

How to get the actual time information of the video recorded with varying frame rate? The file is in .avi format.

When I try to get the initial frame rate and use it to get the time, I get a wrong time information.

Is the variation in frame rate because of video compression methods? If so, how to remove the variation from the video.

Answer (score 0):

`AVI` is a fixed frame rate container, you can read the rate from file header (e.g. see [`AVIFILEINFO::dwRate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details). If some of the frames are dropped and are not actually present in the file - they are zero length frames there. There only way to read this information is to either read the file index section, or stream through the file and check zero length vs. non-zero length frames.